# Raspberry Ubuntu boot error: ASoC: error at snd_soc_dai_startup on fef05700.hdmi: -19

Tags: boot, kernel, crash

I recently installed 'Ubuntu Desktop 21.04' on a sd card for my Raspberry Pi4b and while it seemed fine to start with after one or two reboots I get errors and wasn't able to boot back in again.

I tried again to flash the card with that same image and same thing happened. It was fine in the very first session but then I got this boot error that I haven't been able to solve.

The error message I kept getting was:

```
ASoC: error at snd_soc_dai_startup on fef05700.hdmi: -19
```

I read some comment saying it might be because of non-existing audio on the monitor but Iv'e successfully passed audio from HDMI->3.5mmjack out from the monitor under Raspbian OS.

I see some recent and some threads a few months old with people mentioning the same error messages. Often it leads to discussions involving Kodi.
Seems to be some audio+hdmi related kernel thing?

Here's a recent and similar chat,
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4575
another
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=316295

So last night I tried to find an older Ubuntu image and got a Ubuntu Mate 20.04.3.
This has worked fine and I didn't get that error even after several reboots.
It's using Kernel 5.4.

I also saw another user who reported a 'spontaneous reboot' which I suspect happened to me on my first try. (I wasn't in the room)

I can't use the older Ubuntu as I need the newer 'dma-buf' kernel updates that seem to be post 5.4.

Is there anyone who knows what this issue might be?

Cheers.